# javascript button that fills the current input instead of the first one

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, autofill

I made a button that can fill forms with javascript, but it only fills the first input on the page. I want it to fill whichever input cursor is blinking on.
I need help.
Heres my code:

```html
<script>
  function autoFill() {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0]

    input.value += "only works with the first input";
  }
</script>

<input type="input">
<button type="button" onclick="autoFill()">fill it!</button>
<input type="input">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will track input focus and when button clicked it will fill correct control.

```js
// track current focus
let currFocus;
document.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
  if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') currFocus = e.target;
});

function autoFill() {
  if (currFocus) currFocus.value += "only works with the first input";
}
```

```html
<input type="input">
<button type="button" onclick="autoFill()">fill it!</button>
<input type="input">
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to track the previously focused `input[type="input"]` element using `document.querySelectorAll` via an additional state variable (ie `lastFocus` as shown below). Then, when `autoFill()` is called, populate the `value` of the `lastFocus` element if it exists:

```js
let lastFocus = ''

function autoFill() {

  /* If a last focused input exists, populate it */
  if (lastFocus) {

    var input = document.querySelector('input:focus')
    lastFocus.value += "only works with the first input";
  }
}

/* Iterate each input element in document */
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="input"]').forEach(element => {

  /* Add an "on focus" listener, which sets last focused input*/
  element.addEventListener('focus', event => {
    lastFocus = element;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="input">
<button type="button" onclick="autoFill()">fill it!</button>
<input type="input">
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `focus` and through the attribute `Event.target` get the currently focused element.

*Embrace the function `addEventListener` for binding events.*

```js
let focused;
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    focused = e.target;
  });
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (focused) focused.value += "only works with the first input";
});
```

```html
<input type="input">
<button type="button">fill it!</button>
<input type="input">
```

Comment: Ele he wants to fill the one with focus. To do that he would need to track focus.

Answer (score 0):

you are always setting value of the first input control in your script. You need a way to identify which input was last in focus before clicking auto fill button. Maybe you can add an onfocus handler to each required input and record the last input in focus.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to find out which input box the user is currently typing in. We can do this by attaching **click** event listeners to the individual text boxes. As soon as someone clicks on it to actually type something we update a global variable which holds a reference to just clicked - thus active - object.
First give your text boxes an id so we can distinguish them:

```
<input type="input" id="input1">
<input type="input" id="input2">
```

Afterwards add these lines:

```
var activeInput;
document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("click", toggleActive);
document.getElementById("input2").addEventListener("click", toggleActive);

function autoFill() {
  activeInput.value += "only works with the first input";
}

function toggleActive(e) {
  activeInput = e.target;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added listener for focus event and use one focused object for input.

```js
var focused, inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   
        inputs[i].addEventListener("focus", function(){
            focused = this;
        });
    
}

  function autoFill() {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if(input[i] === focused){
           input[i].value += "auto filled";
      }
    }

    
  }
```

```html
<input type="input">
<button type="button" onclick="autoFill()">fill it!</button>
<input type="input">
```